# ERROR: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to create a lambda from my pushed image in ECR, everything is working fine, Image is also getting created without error, but when I create lambda using ECR image and test it gives error  `libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file:  No Such file or directory.`
I'm creating and pushing images from my ec2 instance based on RHEL.

Docker File

```
    FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7
WORKDIR /doc_dir
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY data.cav .
RUN yum update -y && yum install libgomp -y
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -i custom_url --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}" \ && rm requirements.txt
COPY demo.py ${LAMBDA TASK_ROOT}
CMD ["demo.lambda_handler"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved,
added `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Docker file and in lambda added env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64`

Comment: when i changed the path LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64, the problem was not solved. I found solution by uploading Lambda Layer,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77824735/11742456